# SQL: Put rows at top of query if a column exists elsewhere

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, user-interface

I have a rows in a table that multiple users will view. Users can "favorite" a row, which adds the username/row key to a separate table.

I want to make a query that orders "favorites" to the top. I assume this would require a subquery, but I'm not sure on the best way to proceed.

One idea I had was to query my table where it exists in favorites, and then union all to a query where it doesn't exist in favorites. But I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Join to your separate table and then order by this favorite row. [Without sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and expected output it's hard to give you code...

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like this:

```
select t.*
from t left join
     favorites f
     on t.pk = f.pk and f.userid = @userid
order by (case when f.pk is not null then 1 else 2 end);
```

`pk` is the primary key of the original table used to uniquely identify each row.